# scandir() returns different results to DirectoryIterator

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, virtualbox, scandir

I have an old PHP function that uses `DirectoryIterator` to loop over files in a directory. Today I reloaded our vagrant VM, re-ran the function and found it was returning only the "dot" entries (`.` and `..`).

Running `scandir()` over the same directory returns the full list of files, so I temporarily re-wrote the function to use scandir instead.

The `DirectoryIterator` version has been in production for years, always pointed at the same hard-coded directory. I can't figure out why it is now returning no files, only the "dot" entries. The `DirectoryIterator` version is returning the full list of files just fine on a colleague's machine. It doesn't appear to be a file-permissions issue, since `scandir()` runs correctly in the same code context.

I'm stumped for an explanation. Does anybody know why this might happen?

Comment: Just run into the same problem. What were your conclusions on this one ?

Comment: I did find the answer. It was to do with the sync directory mechanism being used by vagrant/virtualbox. By default, the built-in shared folders mechanism from virtualbox is used. I changed the Vagrantfile to use "nfs" as the sync directory mechanism instead, this solved the problem (I am using a linux host OS, you may need SMB or something else if you use a Windows host). A telltale sign was that DirectoryIterator worked correctly when I tried it on another directory that was outside of my synced directory from the host. See here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage

Comment: Also see this question, which is where I got my answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207799/directoryiterator-ignoring-directories-in-vagrant-synced-folders