# DirectoryIterator ignoring directories in vagrant synced folders

Tags: php, vagrant

I'm using laravel/homestead vagrant box.
When I try to use `DirectoryIterator` for synced folder it returns only the "dot" entries (`..`,`.`).

My vagrant synced folder is called `code` (in vmbox), inside this directory I have my vagrant files and project codes, so when I use `DirectoryIterator` for `/home/vagrant` it list all directories without problem including `code` directory. But when I use it for `/home/vagrant/code`only dot entries shows up, other directories is ignored. `scandir()` works normally and list all directories without a problem.

Edit:
here is the code and outputs:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/home/vagrant') as $fileInfo) {
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
outputs:
.
..
.ssh
.sudo_as_admin_successful
.composer
.local
code
.config
.bash_aliases
.wget-hsts
.npm
```

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/home/vagrant/code') as $fileInfo) {
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
outputs:
.
..
```

```
foreach (scandir('/home/vagrant/code') as $fileInfo) {
    echo $fileInfo. "<br>\n";
}
outputs:
.
..
.vagrant
Homestead.yaml
LICENSE.txt
Vagrantfile
after.sh
aliases
bin
composer.json
composer.lock
homestead
project
readme.md
scripts
src
```

Comment: So no directory exists inside `code`?

Comment: no, multiple directories exist inside `code` but `DirectoryIterator` not listing them.

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: edited main post for codes and outputs.

Comment: Code looks ok. Will need machine access then to further debug which is out of the scope of this platform

Comment: unfortunately i can't give access to the machine since its a local VM.

Comment: tried using `clearstatcache()` before `DirectoryIterator` ?

Comment: @Pilan tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Try calling a directory which DirectoryIterator doesnt to gain some insights: `new DirectoryIterator('/home/vagrant/code/project')` maybe there is an access-right issue.

Comment: @Pilan tried other directories inside `code` same thing happened, all directories permissions are 777. i'm not sure but if it was access-right issue `scandir()` should act same right?

Comment: weird thing, i tried to change directories permissions and ownership but they didn't changed, there was no error after running command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with vagrant. I debugged a little and found out the issue is the in the **file type** of the synced folder and not with the **DirectoryIterator**

### Problem

**Vagrantfile** - folder sync config issue

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/var/www/virtual/machine/folder", "/var/www/host/machine/folder"
```

In the above configuration I did not specify any file **type** for the **sync** folder. because of that, Vagrant automatically choose the best synced folder option for my environment

### Solution

I have changed the sync folder **file type** to **"nfs"** which solved the issue

**Vagrantfile** - solution

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/var/www/virtual/machine/folder", "/var/www/host/machine/folder", type: "nfs"
```

### Note

> Before using synced folders backed by NFS, the host machine must have nfsd installed, the NFS server daemon. This comes pre-installed on Mac OS X, and is typically a simple package install on Linux.

Comment: for people who are using homestead you need to add `type: "nfs"` inside `Homestead.yaml` file, under `folders` option: [Configuring Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-homestead)