# PHP DirectoryIterator class returns no entries in VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: php, virtualbox

I am running a VirtualBox instance for a web server with nginx and php. I discovered that when I try to iterate over a directory using the `DirectoryIterator` class from PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), then it works fine for standard folders inside the VM. But if I try to iterate over directory entries for a shared folder (mapped from host to guest), then `.` and `..` are the only entries I get back.

I can iterate over a shared folder from PHP by using the `opendir` and `readdir` functions, that works just fine. But if I try to do it with `DirectoryIterator`, no love. That tells me that the files are fundamentally there and accessible to PHP, just not if I use this specific method.

I assume there must be some kind of OS-level interface that is used by `DirectoryIterator`, but which is not supported by VirtualBox shared folders. I just have no idea what to do about it.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207799/directoryiterator-ignoring-directories-in-vagrant-synced-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207799/directoryiterator-ignoring-directories-in-vagrant-synced-folders)

Comment: That is precisely what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who are facing the problem, the mismatching version of guest additions may be the key.